Vite Proxy config leading to infinite loop
I'm building a simple chat app with Vite + React.
I have a form that accepts text input and when that input is submitted, it calls a fetch to hit my own API:
        const response = await fetch('/api/chat', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ messages, model }),
        });

I have a server set up to accept these post requests (/src/api/chat.ts)
But the main issue here is my vite config, which is as follows:
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api/chat': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        selfHandleResponse: true,
        configure: (proxy, options) => {
          proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req: any, res) => {
            // This code runs infinitely
            console.log('Sending Request to the Target:', req.method, req.url);
            handleProxyRequest(req, res);
          });
          proxy.on('error', (err, req, res) => {
            console.error('Proxy error:', err, req, res);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

If I submit the form or otherwise make the post to https://localhost:3000/api/chat, I get an infinite loop of logs:
Sending Request to the Target: POST /api/chat
Sending Request to the Target: POST /api/chat
Sending Request to the Target: POST /api/chat
...

My expectation is that this config would just accept the single POST request and send it on to the handleProxyRequest function, but instead it just infinitely loops on that code block.
What am I missing here?

your proxy is on port 3000, your target is also on port 3000 - you've created the "loop"
